# How to add a field to a JSON object with the jq command?

Tags: json, jq

I have this JSON data:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "module": {
        "data": {
            "item_i77f664a2": {
                "id": "i77f664a2",
                "tag": "item",
                "fields": {
                    "cartItemId": 2012636322
                },
                "type": "biz"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to add `{"operation":"delete"}` right below `cartItemId` and then save the JSON data to a file. The result that I want is like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "module": {
        "data": {
            "item_i77f664a2": {
                "id": "i77f664a2",
                "tag": "item",
                "fields": {
                    "cartItemId": 2012636322,
                    "operation": "delete"
                },
                "type": "biz"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried:

```
jq '.module.data.item_i77f664a2.fields + {"operation":"delete"}' > data.json
```

But it doesn't save the JSON data with the output that I want like above. How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This type of update is where the magic of `+=` comes into play.  With your input, the following invocation:

```
jq '.module.data.item_i77f664a2.fields += {"operation":"delete"}'
```

produces the output you indicate you want:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "module": {
    "data": {
      "item_i77f664a2": {
        "id": "i77f664a2",
        "tag": "item",
        "fields": {
          "cartItemId": 2012636322,
          "operation": "delete"
        },
        "type": "biz"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I am not sure that this will produce what you want in similar circumstances, as you have referenced "item_i77f61ee2".

Comment: This appends at the end, how to insert it in the first place instead at the end?

Comment: @karthik101 - '.module.data.item_i77f664a2.fields |=  [{"operation":"delete"}] + .'

Comment: @peak wouldn't that just merge the two? Can you specify, specifically, "add this new property after property `cartItemId`? (E.g. suppose there were numerous `fields` instead of only one.

Comment: @JoshM - `+` is polymorphic: it can be used for both merging of objects, and concatenation of arrays, and etc. If that doesn't answer your question, maybe you would care to ask a new SO question ...

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to @peak for his answer!

Just want to add,

Creating a blank json file:

```
echo "{}" > config.json
```

File Content:

```
{}
```

Then add properties to the file:

```
echo "$(jq '. += {"url": "https://url.com"}' config.json)" > config.json
```

File Content:

```
{
    "url": "https://url.com"
}
```

One  more property:

```
echo "$(jq '. += {"name": "a Name"}' config.json)" > config.json
```

File Content:

```
{
    "url": "https://url.com",
    "name": "a Name"
}
```

If you have variables set and want to use that value (ie. Azure Build Pipelines) you can pass in that value as an argument (`urlarg` in this case):

```
URL="https://url.com"
echo "$(jq --arg urlarg "$URL" '. += {"url": $urlarg}' config.json)" > config.json
```